# Firebird: Using global variable

Tags: sql, firebird

I would like to assign a value to a variable which is used in an sql code in firebird. The MySQL-Code would be:

```
SET @x = 1;
SELECT @x;
```

What is the correspondent Firebird-Code?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5):

To define a user-defined session-specific variable in Firebird you can use [rdb$set_context](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-set-context.html).

The correspondent Firbird-code for your MySql-example would be:

```
select rdb$set_context('USER_SESSION', 'x', 1) from rdb$database
select rdb$get_context('USER_SESSION', 'x') from rdb$database
```

**Notes:**

1.) Be aware that variable names are case-sensitive.

2.) Internally variable values are [stored with datatype `VARCHAR(255)`](http://www.janus-software.com/fbmanual/manual.php?book=psql&topic=49) and thus casted to `VARCHAR(255)`!!

3.) The maximum number of variables is 1000.

4.) You don't need to refer to `rdb$database`:

```
select rdb$get_context('USER_SESSION', 'x') from some_table_name
```

would work as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert in Firebird, but I believe it would be something like this...

```sql
set term ^ ;

EXECUTE BLOCK
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE x int;
BEGIN
  x = 1; 
  --do whatever you want with x, there's no such thing 
  --as to select the variable value to print it
END
^

set term ; ^
```