# Large scripts with variables in Firebird

Tags: firebird, batch-processing

I need to run a large script involving variables in Firebird 2.5.

Is it possible to do this without using EXECUTE BLOCK?

In .NET, using FbBatchExecution it fails with "Error reading data from the connection".

In my SQL Manager client, it fails with "Size of query text exceeds 64k limit. Client libraray won't be able to proceed it".

So it seems EXECUTE BLOCK is bound by the 64kb limit as well, which makes it useless for anything large.

Aside from using temp tables, is there a way to declare and use variables within a large (or even very large) script?

Comment: You can use ISQL - Firebird Interactive SQL Tool

Comment: @dataol: I am using the .net providers "FirebirdSql.Data.Isql" and it doesn't work. Does isql normally support declaring variables within a script (not within an execute block)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without `EXECUTE BLOCK` by utilizing (global) variables and iteratively executing the sql commands.

In Firebird you can declare and use temporary session-global variables (alternatively transaction-global) by using [`rdb$set_context('USER_SESSION','VAR_NAME', VALUE)`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-set-context.html) and  [`rdb$get_context(...)`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-get-context.html).

But there are some restrictions, [more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29793290/2306907).